# Dictation on macOS frequently stalls the computer

Tags: voice-dictation

For the physically incapacitated, macOS dictation is a lifesaver.

However, I find that frequently using this utility grinds the system to a halt. Responsiveness goes down to 0 over a few seconds, the fan kicks in, I have to go to Activity Monitor and kill anything with the word 'speech' in it.

This feature has become completely unusable.

I'm considering a fresh installation of macOS.

But is there anything that can be done, short of this drastic measure?

And what can I do to debug this phenomenon? Simply reinstalling is not intelligently going to the root of the problem. So how to go to the root?

Comment: Does this happen in safe mode? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: I would also keep Activity Monitor open and see what specific processes are slowing things down. Then we can look at the system logs and see if it is logging anything useful that would tell us why this is happening, or at least give us something more to search for online.